# Cassandra cluster slow reads

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, cassandra-2.0, titan

I'm doing some prototyping/benchmarking on Titan, a NoSQL graph database. Titan uses Cassandra as back-end.
I've got one Titan-Cassandra VM running and two cassandra VM's. 
Each of them owning roughly 33% of the data (replication factor 1):
[image: Titan-Cassandra Setup]

---

All the machines have 4GB of RAM and 4 i7 cores (shared).
I'm interested in all adjacent nodes, so I call Rexter (a REST API) with: http://192.168.33.10:8182/graphs/graph/vertices/35082496/both

These are the results (in seconds):
[image: results]
Note that with the two nodes test, the setup was the exact same as described above, except there is one Cassandra node less. The two nodes (titan-casssandra and Cassandra) both owned 50% of the data.

Titan is the fastest with 1 node and performance tend to degrade when more nodes are added. `This is the opposite of what distribution should accomplish, so obviously I'm doing something wrong, right?`
These is my Cassandra config:
Cassandra YAML: http://pastebin.com/ZrsRdtuD
Node 2 and node 3 have the exact same YAML file. The only difference is the listen_address (this is equal to the node's IP)

How to improve this performance?
If you need any additional information, don't hesitate to reply.
Thanks

Comment: Are all of your VMs running on the same host?

Comment: Are you able to distribute the titan component, too? You may be suffering from diminishing data locality as you add more nodes.

Comment: @AndyTolbert Yes all my VM's are on the same host. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Adam No titan is not distributable, but my guess this is not necessary, because its backend Cassandra is.

Comment: @Casper, it likely is. For example, if you have cassandra nodes are sharing the same physical Disk, they will be competing with one another for reads / writes.  I wouldn't expect better numbers when benchmarking and adding nodes if those nodes are on the same hardware (unless you have a large system with a lot of available resources and are using separate disks for each VM).

Comment: I'll try some physical machines. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyTolbert sadly the performance degraded even more. I ran the test on a Macbook Air i7 4GB RAM (Titan Cassandra) and a Macbook Pro 16GB RAM (Cassandra). Replication factor: 1 (50% share), read/write quorum. CPU and memory usage are low on both machines. The machines were connected via an adhoc network (direct connection 1ms latency max). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Casper Hrmm, it's hard for me to say not understanding much about your set up.  Also I'm not too experienced in Titans data model and how it distributes data among partitions.  When I do benchmarking / performance assessments I usually find it best to test in the environment I'm going to be deploying to (EC2/GCE/Azure/etc.) so I understand the impacts of changing the environment.  EC2 spot instances run really cheap (cents an hour).